# Using React in a small subset of an ASP 4 MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have a very large ASP application that uses reflection to load external modules as Areas.

I am developing one Area right now that is a prime candidate for something like React. Since this Area shares a Layout as the rest of the project, I don't want to simply include React as a core feature of the product itself, and would like to keep it isolated to just this module/area.

How would I support something like React, where the rest of our project isn't on ES6, and I'd want to keep it isolated to just this one module?

Comment: you want to use react at front end or you want to build entire functionality using react?

Comment: @VikramSaini Not sure of the difference, but since it's a frontend library I'd want to use it there.

Comment: in that case i have done that thing using spring and reactjs and es6 will not interfere with your back end in that case.Let me share the code in the answer

Comment: ASP is a legacy technology that has no "Reflection" support. Please correct the wording of your question (and titile) to indicate this is ASP.NET MVC, which is completely different than ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure pusher to bind your events with your front end.
Here are some things you will need to do to configure pusher"-

- sign up to pusher and you will get your credentials

I have initialized pusher class in my **controller** class

```
@RestController
@SessionAttributes(GeneralConstants.ID_SESSION_SHOPPING_CART)
public class CartController {

    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    private Pusher pusher;

    /**
     * Method executed after the object is created
     * that creates an instance of the Pusher object and
     * populates the list of products
     *you will get your pusher constants after signing in pusher
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void configure() {
        pusher = new Pusher(
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_ID, 
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_KEY, 
                PusherConstants.PUSHER_APP_SECRET
        );
        @RequestMapping(value = "/products", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,  
            produces = "application/json")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
```

Here is my **html page** which is acting as view.
Import required cdn and you can also use webpack if you do not want to use cdn

```
   <!-- React -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.1/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Libs -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.1/fetch.js"></script>
      <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Pusher Config -->
      <script th:inline="javascript">
        var PUSHER_APP_KEY = /*[[${pusher_app_key}]]*/ 'NA';
        var PUSHER_CHANNEL_NAME = /*[[${pusher_channel}]]*/ 'NA';
      </script>

      <!-- App/Components -->
      <script type="text/babel" src="/js/components/app.js"></script>
```

app.js will be the entry point and in this class pusher will listen to the events and bind them with the controller

**App.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


import scriptLoader from 'D:/Training Softwares/shopping-cart-pusher-master/src/main/resources/static/js/apps.js';



import Header from 'D:/Training Softwares/shopping-cart-pusher-master/src/main/resources/static/js/components/header.js';




var App  = React.createClass ({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return { items: [], products: [] };
      },

      componentWillMount: function() {
          alert("snake2ee")
        this.pusher = new Pusher("", {
          encrypted: true,
          cluster: 'ap2',
        });
        this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe("your event");
        this.total = 0;
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {


        fetch('/products').then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(this.getProductsSuccess);
      },
      componentWillUnmount: function() {

        // Unbind from channel events
        this.channel.unbind();

        // Unsubscribe from the Pusher channel
        this.pusher.unsubscribe(this.channel);

        // Unregister by assign them to an empty function
        this.getProductsSuccess = function() {};

      },



      getProductsSuccess: function(response) {
          alert("in success")

        this.setState({
            products: response
        });
      },


      render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <Header products={this.state.products} />

          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you misunderstood my question though. I'm running an ASP site with ES5, and no support for ES6. I want to create an Area that is ES6 compatible and able to load modules, for React purposes. This question is about that case.